# Terraform Plan stuck at Terraform:Plan task in ADO pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure

[image]I am trying to follow the below link to deploy an App Service using Terraform via Azure Dev Ops Pipeline

[AzureDevOpsLabs](https://azuredevopslabs.com/labs/vstsextend/terraform/)

My terraform files are given below :

**webapp.tf**

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.0" 
  backend "azurerm" {
    storage_account_name = "__terraformstorageaccount__"
    container_name       = "terraform"
    key                  = "terraform.tfstate"
    }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  tenant_id       = var.tenant_id
  client_id       = var.client_id
  client_secret   = var.client_secret
  subscription_id = var.subscription_id
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "dev" {
  name     = var.resource_group_name
  location = var.resource_group_location
}

resource "azurerm_app_service_plan" "dev" {
  name                = var.appserviceplan
  location            = var.resource_group_location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name

  sku {
    tier = "Free"
    size = "F1"
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.dev
  ]
}

resource "azurerm_app_service" "dev" {
  name                = var.appservicename
  location            = azurerm_app_service_plan.dev.location 
  resource_group_name = azurerm_app_service_plan.dev.location
  app_service_plan_id = azurerm_app_service_plan.dev.id
}
```

**var.tf**

```
variable "client_id" {}

variable "client_secret" {}

variable "tenant_id" {}

variable "subscription_id" {}

variable "appserviceplan" {}

variable "appservicename" {}

variable "resource_group_name" {}

variable "resource_group_location" {}
```

The actual values are given in the pipeline variables

I have deployed the same app service directly using open source terraform and it worked fine.

But the "Terraform:Plan" step is stuck in the Release Pipeline as shown in the screenshot.
Any idea why this is happening and the plan is not finishing properly

[image]

I have disabled Terraform Init and enabled debugging. But it still fails at Terraform Apply and i see the below logs. The task never finishes

**Terraform Apply Task**

```
Exit code 0 received from tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe'
STDIO streams have closed for tool 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe'
provider=azurerm
commandOptions=-auto-approve
workingDirectory=C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform
environmentServiceNameAzureRM=a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62
which 'terraform'
found: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe'
which 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe'
found: 'C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe'
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe arg: apply
C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe arg: -auto-approve
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 auth param serviceprincipalid = ***
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 auth param serviceprincipalkey = ***
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 data subscriptionid = xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 auth param tenantid = xxxx-xxxxxx
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 auth param serviceprincipalid = ***
a8ee372e-0734-4e50-aa5a-e19d9e5f2a62 auth param serviceprincipalkey = ***
exec tool: C:\hostedtoolcache\windows\terraform\1.1.5\x64\terraform.exe
arguments:
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When running Terraform from within a non-interactive pipeline you must add the flag `-input=false` , otherwise Terraform will hang expecting user input.

See documentation here: https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/plan#input-false

Comment: I get this message now after putting -input=false in the additional command arguments in the terraform:plan task

Comment: Ok after adding that input=false, things worked. Thanks a lot for your help.