# Terraform plan task stuck and not progressing- and no error

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I have 2 terraform pipelines. The only difference in them is the variable group and the service connection.
One works great and has been so for months. The other one, however, gets stuck at Terraform plan.

The one which is stuck is a new one, but nothing that should make it stuck. The service connection has both `Owner` and `Storage Blob Data contributor` RBAC roles.

I can see that the state file gets created and is leased (aka locked by Terraform), but remains so and does not get past.

I tried putting `System.Debug` to `true` in the pipeline variables and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71680143/terraform-plan-stuck-at-terraformplan-task-in-ado-pipeline) w.r.t setting input to false but nothing works. I do not even have a clue why is it stuck.

Can anyone help in at least locating where can I find logs or some clues.

I am using this [task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=charleszipp.azure-pipelines-tasks-terraform).

Also, the tfstate file which gets locked (apparently even terraform plan creates the tfstate file- I didn't know that. Only thought apply creates one), has the following contents:

```
{
  "version": 4,
  "terraform_version": "1.5.2",
  "serial": 1,
  "lineage": "xxxxxxxx-a4df-bdd0-xxxx-xxxxxxxx",
  "outputs": {},
  "resources": [],
  "check_results": null
}
```

the task looks like this:

```
 task: TerraformCLI@0
 displayName: 'Terraform plan'
 inputs:
   command: plan
   environmentServiceName: $(serviceConnection)
   runAzLogin: true
   commandOptions: '-var-file vars/devfile.tfvars'
```

Since the other pipeline works, and only config values are different, I believe there is no logic error, and if so, I would expect it to throw an error.

What else should I be doing? I am running out of ideas, without the lack of some error output.

The last message just says this

```
/usr/local/bin/terraform plan -var-file vars/devfile.tfvars
```

Comment: Do you have access to run the plan on your machine? Does it work there?

Comment: Unfortunately, I am WFH today and my org has restricted access in a way, that I can't do it , using my account, from home. Running as me in an IDE, gives me the error : building account: could not acquire access token to parse claims: running Azure CLI: exit status 1: ERROR: AADSTS530003: Your device is required to be managed to access this resource. Then even device flow does not work.

Comment: But since this is running from a Azure Devops pipeline with a service principal, I would have expected this to run.

Comment: What is the build agent you are using for the new pipeline, is it the same as the first one? Also update the question and share the pipeline that gets stuck as well.

Comment: Ok- it has finally failed , after an hour with the message (earlier I would cancel after 20 odd mins, as this would normally take 1 min) │ Original Error: Cannot register providers: Microsoft.Compute. Looking at my target subscription- this provider is still "registering" More with the message: Terraform automatically attempts to register the Resource Providers it supports to
│ ensure it's able to provision resources.
If you don't have permission to register Resource Providers you may wish to use the
│ "skip_provider_registration" flag in the Provider block to disable this functionality.

Comment: I will try to find out why my subscription still has this provider registering.